# lldb cannot print TLS variable

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

I've decided to use TLS variables on my C project to define some variables that should be valid throughout thread scope.

Here's my declaration : 
`static __thread char log_username[100];`

however, for some reason the lldb debugger fail to show them for the following reason :

```
(lldb) print log_username[2]
error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of variable log_username: 
No TLS data currently exists for this thread.
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

The debugger states that TLS data is currently not available, but if I use simple printf, it works.

Any idea how to resolve this, or just treat it as debugger limitation that I can live with ...

Comment: In [this LLDB tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) there's a section named "Examining Thread State" which shows you commands to list threads and to select thread context. Not knowing if this is the problem, you might want to select the right thread context for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lldb doesn't currently support thread local storage variables on OS X (not sure about Linux.)  You can work around this by making accessor functions for your TLS variables, and calling those after selecting the appropriate thread.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Linux debugging an OpenMP chunk, I could print TLVs with LLDB only after changing from GCC to Clang and installing the LLVM library